# C# Reading Bitmap from Stream

Tags: c#, image, stream

I've a network stream which sends a name and a picture. Name and picture start and end with a specific word
Example:
BeginNameXXXXXXXEndNameBeginPicYYYYYYYYYEndPic
I'll collect the stream in blocks and check if the last block contains the stop word of the picture.

```
byte[] data = new byte[2048];
int numBytesRead = stream.Read(data, 0, 2048);
if (numBytesRead > 0)
{
code += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, numBytesRead);
}
```

If yes I'll stop collecting and divide the String into the name part and the picture part.
In principle I should have now a string only containing the picture.
Afterwards I try to save it as image but I only get an exception on the last code step

```
byte[] toEncodeAsBytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(code);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
ms.Position = 0;
var image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
```

Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Drawing.dll

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: If you have text values marking the beginning and end of the value, it's probably not encoded directly as a binary image, but rather as base64, such that you first need to decode the base64 data to get the bytes for the final image.

Comment: I've tried that also

```
byte[] toEncodeAsBytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(code);

string returnValue = Convert.ToBase64String(toEncodeAsBytes);

byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(returnValue);

```
With the same result...

Comment: But that's not quite right. You don't convert to a base64 string. You already have a base64 string, so skip that part. You can also skip getting the ascii bytes, since you also already had a string variable.